# Qt,C++: How to recognize clicked objects in QList

Tags: c++, qt

I was looking for any solution for this problem, but nothing found.

I have something like this:
[image]

Those rectangles are my objects. I want to make them selectable - when I click on red rectangle I want to see that this one is selected. If I have those objects saved in QList, can I select exactly that rectangle that I clicked on, and i.e edit it's preferencies?
How to refer to rectangle that I selected?

Comment: A `QList` of what? Please show the code that creates the rectangles.

Comment: It seems to me that you are using _QGraphicsScene_. If that is indeed the case its [selectionChanged](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#selectionChanged) signal is what you need. As for making a _QGraphicsItem_ selectable, use [setFlags](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#setFlags).

Comment: I am still waiting for some feedback on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a [QGraphicsScene](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html) and [QGraphicsItems](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html)/[Objects](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsobject.html), you can call "[QGraphicsItem::setFlags](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#setFlags)(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable)" on your QGraphicsItem and then in your [QGraphicsItem::paint](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#paint)(..) method check if the option->state is set to QStyle::State_Selected, drawing different properties in this case. If you want a good example of how to do it, i recommend you to read third part of the chapter 8 in the "C++ GUI Programming with Qt, second edition" book.